# Can anyone tell me why this question is illegitimate and is being closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I do not see any reason for this question getting closed: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802265/what-are-the-python-features-you-found-unintuitive-or-surprising-closed

Could any of you provide specific reasons why?

Comment: Well, coming on the back of the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801921/wtf-moments-in-c-programming) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801774/wtf-moments-in-python) probably didn't help

Comment: @Marc I don't even understand why my first WTF question was closed when in fact a question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668/confessions-of-your-worst-wtf-moment/349876 (which is worse in a sense that it is broader in topic) is left open. Is SO prejudiced?

Comment: @OTZ, the other WTF question is much older. SO has grown and focusses more on the serious questions, not the discussions. If you like to discuss, you can go to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: also, yelling "f**k you" to people who vote to close isn't going to get you any friends.  I'm deleting all those comments; please keep it more civil or get suspended, kthx.

Comment: The argument that your argumentative question be left open just because some other argumentative question is still open is itself quite argumentative.

Comment: I need a list of all the people that claimed "it's ok to leave those terrible questions around; people won't use them to justify opening new questions" -- every single time it happens they should need to give me 5 rep each

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Not painful enough; also, not enough rep available in the known universe.

Comment: @michael need a supersecret "migrate to programmers" option for mods.  @Pisk there is enough rep, but unfortunately it is bound up within Skeet's event horizon.

Comment: @Will We had several mod flags on [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) that seemed to imply users thought we had that option. I told them there was no such thing -- the secret remains safe

Comment: Downvoting this question doesn't help anyone; the SO question(s) may not be good, but this question is a reasonable request for clarification about how the system works from a new user. +1.

Comment: @OTZ, as a followup to @Gamecat's answer, here is Jeff (the admin) on [older questions being grandfathered in](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53528/dealing-with-very-old-off-topic-questions/53531#53531).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's simple: It's subjective and/or argumentative and might bear the potential for a nice flamewar.

Comment: It's certainly not argumentative. And how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python Isn't this question equally subjective? I don't see how a question like this would yield a flamewar.

Comment: @OTZ: It's argumentative. One might say that he found the syntax unintuitive, or that the print-method now needs parentheses with 3.x, or that it's strongly typed...it's a conglomerate of *very* subjective opinions. You could also ask `Why don't you like Windows?` on SuperUser...would be the same.

Comment: If someone posts an answer, e.g. a syntax he thinks is unintuitive,  and people on SO happen to agree, the answer gets up votes; if not, it won't get any or receive down votes instead, in which case visibility decreases. They won't argue -- instead they express their opinion via voting.  That's the beauty of a voting-based QA system.

Comment: @OTZ: BTW, the hidden features question is two years old. Stackoverflow used to be more inclusionist in the past. It has outgrown that phase.

Comment: @Tadeusz: For values of *"more inclusionist"* that mean *"didn't yet have a functioning system for keeping the focus"*...

Answer (score 14):

Aside from the question itself, you are racking up a significant number of downvotes because of your attitude toward other users.  You have been abusive in your responses and comments, which is inappropriate behavior for Stack Overflow.

For example, before Will edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688602/sum-numbers-in-an-array/3688647#3688647), you started it with

> This is probably one of the dumbest
>   questions on SO.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588525/how-to-understand-big-chunk-of-code/3589810#3589810), which you start with

> What a load of garbage on this page.
>
> You guys couldn't even introduce tree
>   -CFft after all these hours? Seriously, if you don't know the
>   answer, just don't say anything.

could have been worded much better than that.

We are trying to encourage people to participate, to ask even the simplest questions.  Many users get driven away from forums when the experts on those forums start demeaning the "newbies".  So far, this has been avoided here for the most part and we'd like to maintain this civil atmosphere.