# Is "WTF" allowed to appear in question title or description?

Tags: discussion

Is **WTF** censored?

Comment: sorry, didn't mean do delete your comment, for context: waffles changed the title of the question to W*F as a joke and it got rolled back.

Comment: It is not.  It is a very effective filter for moron questions, we like it.

Comment: @waffles no problemo. i'd play around like the way u do had i had mod's capabilities.

Comment: @OTZ, the title editing was a general thing anybody with 2K rep could do, the comment deletion is something I **totally** avoid and do not do. Moderators deleting comments cause they feel they should not be there can cause a lot of trouble. I was deleting my comment and the mouse slipped, really.

Comment: @waffles, this merely reveals to me that even diamond mods cannot undelete comments. Interesting.

Comment: @Popular I think I can ... there is just no UI ... its a pain in the behind

Comment: @waffles Only because you're a dev though; I'm pretty sure mods have no mechanism to undelete comments

Comment: Why is OTZ boxed? What'd he do?

Comment: @Toronto - It may be automatic, due to all the downvoting on his questions, or it may be related to the items discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65989/answer-deletion-by-community-is-a-100-penalty-why-no-reason-for-deletion-is-pro) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/can-anyone-tell-me-why-this-question-is-illegitimate-and-is-being-closed).

Comment: @Brad: After a quick peek at these I have to assume that he was boxed for not appealing to whiners' whinings. That's not a good reason.

Comment: @Toronto Just wanted to say I appreciate your concern.

Comment: You're not the only one who's been banned for breaking rules that don't exist, OTZ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### WTF?

f*** and brainf*** are discouraged cause corporate filters block content, which already caused issues in the past.

Occasionally people will edit out f*ck and so on, which causes occasional storms on meta.

That said:

- "IE is doing xyz, WTF?"

Is a horrible title, it conveys a judgement call which really does not add to your problem and does look unprofessional. I would totally support people editing it to

- "IE sometimes renders pages with frobs under bla conditions"

Wow, much better.

The same could be argued about the actual body of a question, how is WTF making questions any better? I totally support editing a question and making it much clearer by removing the WTF? statement **and** offering a general improvement beyond that.

That said, no I do not think its in the "censored" list if such a list exists.

Comment: Now it ain't...

Comment: @OTZ All question posted on meta are presented-for-waffles-enjoyment. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is about the deletion of your question [WTF moments in C programming (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801921/wtf-moments-in-c-programming-closed). That was just the normal process of cleaning the site. Closed questions of no obvious value are deleted on a reasonably regular basis by the action of 10k+ reputation users.

You'll note that this was not accompanied by a loss of reputation to you because it is *not* a punishment. Indeed, given that this particular question was rather heavily downvoted you'll get some rep back the next time a recalc runs on your account.

Comment: Actually it does have some impact, if you ask a stream of poor questions and they get deleted, it may impact your ability to ask questions on the site.

Comment: Also, I think that could possibly work as a question on programmers "Most awesome C++ war story"

Comment: Ah...I'd momentarily forgotten the new lots-a-bad-questions trigger. Thanks, pancakes.

Comment: u like me, dont u?

Comment: @waffles i did, though it wasn't the "most awesome". http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/wtf-moments-in-python-programming-closed it got closed pretty quickly.