# "Title-only" questions (i.e. questions without body) should be allowed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

There is a type of questions like [this entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66113/is-wtf-allowed-to-appear-in-question-title-or-description) where the structure is simple
enough that a question title surely covers the entire description without
further explanation.  Requiring question body for those questions would be
redundant and would impose an unnecessary burden on users.

So what I think would be nicer is to have a checkbox, saying "Empty body" to omit the body input.

Comment: Voting to reopen this question since this is much older and has an official response. The other question should have this as a duplicate target instead.

Answer (score 38):

I disagree.  Having a required body forces you to think about "what further detail" should I supply for this question.

We don't need more questions, we need better questions

Comment: there is the other side though: it'll increase the number of valid questions - thus more contents on SO.

Comment: We don't need *more* questions, we need *better* questions.

Comment: u r missing the point, sir. **questions *can* be good *and* short.**

Comment: @OTZ: Can you? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @thyrgle im not sure... actually im not sure what's being asked.

Comment: @OTZ: Can you *really* post a short but good question?

Comment: @thyrgle Yes, like *When will a computer surpass human intelligence?*

Comment: @OTZ: There is so much more you could add, you have no idea.

Comment: i dont know how u got the impression. but that aside, answerers would compensate for any lack of information if they felt like it.

Comment: @OTZ: Another problem, is it is subjective. Define smarter? Also, it's always nice to show what research you have done on the matter.

Comment: just how long are you going to continue this off-topic conversation?

Comment: @OTZ: It's not off-topic.

Comment: "When will a computer surpass human intelligence?" was your example of a good question? That would get closed in about a minute

Comment: @Michael: Unless unit Sk33t reopens it to reply "happened already"

Answer (score 8):

> "When will a computer surpass human
>   intelligence?"

This is a discussion question, SO is not a discussion site. Its a technical/programming Q&A site. Any question actually appropriate to SO is 99.9% likely to require further details.

Answer (score 8):

I strongly disagree with this view. The title has an important role in questions and using it to contain (the only) content of a question is abuse of the title field and indicative of low quality in general.

## Justification

The title is useful for much more than just "the first part of my question". I think in a good question the title and body should be used as outlined in the next two sub-sections.

### The title

The title in my view is your "hook", *this is your **one** chance to entice readers*; it's what the experts you hope will answer your question see mostly when scrolling through a big list of question. (It's important to search engines too). Thus I would suggest that a good title to does two things:

1. **Make it clear to a potential reader what *area* your question is in.**

   Some of the really basic filtering is done through Tags, e.g. differentiating [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) from [php](/questions/tagged/php), so you can and should be somewhat more specific.
2. **Make it sound interesting and make it obvious you've done basic research.**

   Given a choice between a harder, well written question and a corresponding poor question I think most experts (i.e. the people you hope will answer) would pick the former.

### The body

Once you've hooked someone in this is where the guts of the question lives. My expectation when reading a question is that *the body is not a continuation of the title*, instead it is the details and substance of the question. It should be free-standing and complete. An interesting title followed by no details in the body is almost always going to be disappointing to readers.

I don't recall ever reading a text book where the chapter/section titles are blended into the contents, or the only content. In my view in order to make your question a valuable part of a Q&A site (i.e. a useful reference for future readers) this should be the case here too.

The separation of content, presentation and structure in documents is generally seen as a good thing. The title of a question is a structural thing, the content is the body - don't blur the line between the two.

---

*If you think you can ask a question in just the title alone then 99% of the time I think it's probably one or more of: not very interesting, not well researched or not well written*. Odds are it'll attract close votes for:

1. Too broad - e.g. "How is X implemented?"
2. Duplicate - there are very few simple, sensible questions that haven't been asked already. Even if it it isn't a duplicate adding some examples would go along way.
3. Not clear enough to answer

Comment: +1 Absolutely. Title and body are different things that serve different purposes. Each has a single responsibility, and their roles shouldn't be confused.

Comment: If you don't have context for your question to basically say why you are asking, you don't have a question!

Answer (score 5):

Think of it this way: forcing people to fill in the message body trains people in the skill of writing doco and/or requirements. In the example you provided, you should have explained **why** you thought it was censored. Add some context to the question, because context can be vitally important. *You* may know exactly what you are talking about, but you are posting questions on an international forum  but you cannot be sure that *anyone else* knows what you are talking about.

If your question truly fits within the title, then it is probably a very simple question with a very simple answer that you probably didn't need to ask.